# is it possible to edit Magento creation date? and how?

Tags: magento, date, edit, product, creation

hey there? I have a problem and I need to edit product's creation date on magento to arrange my products to the right order, but I just cannot find out how to do it? can anyone here help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if you are wishing to do this via the admin section or programmatically in some sort of script.  The created_at field is a core field found in the "catalog_product_entity" table.  Programmatically you could do it along these lines:

```
$productId = 123; //use your own product id here
$myProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$myProduct->setCreatedAt(strtotime("now"))->save(); 
// I put strtotime("now") as an example - use whatever date you need to.
$myProduct->unset();
```

However, you could reconsider using a different attribute to order by.  There is  a "position" field, or use a custom order attribute.  The created_at is useful to keep as a proper point of reference to when the product was actually entered into the system.

To use the position attribute, you can order your products in the admin by going to "categories" and then choosing the "category products" tab.  You should see the position field as one of the columns. Set this for each product with the lowest number you want to appear at the top.

Comment: Please note that there is a specific Magento site on [magento.stackexchange.com](http://magento.stackexchange.com/)